# How does GAE/JDO convert Entities to domain objects?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

In the App Engine's JDO implementation, object types are saved as a 'Kind' with the Entity that is persisted to the datastore. When these Entities are fetched back out of the datastore, they are automatically returned (in some layer of JDO) as the original object type. What confuses me is that only the simple name of the class is saved; not the full path. So how is the JVM loading the correct class?

For example, if I have com.project.domain.User and I save an instance of this class to the datastore, only 'User' is defined for the Entity kind. When I use JDO to select this data back out, I get a com.project.domain.User back. How did GAE/JDO know to load com.project.domain.User and not com.project.other.domain.User?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JDO provider (GAE isn't actually involved in this equation) keeps an internal mapping from entities to tables.  Sometimes it forms this from various xml files, sometimes it forms this through annotations (depends on your coding style).  In this map table names are actually mapped to fully qualified classes.

If you were storing both kinds of User objects then JDO would give you an exception because they'd be using the same table.  You'd fix this by specifying a different table (via annotation or xml configuration).  This specification would go into JDO's internal mapping.  Then JDO would know how to resolve the entity correctly.

Comment: So then how is this internal mapping persisted between JVM startup/shutdown? I havent defined anything in XML or annotation.

Comment: Actually GAE is involved in this since the "JDO provider" is GAE (or rather their plugin for DataNucleus). If you want to work it out, it comes through this class   http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/trunk/src/org/datanucleus/store/appengine/DatastorePersistenceHandler.java